# OpenUI5 sap.m.Input Currency Formatting

Tags: formatting, sapui5, currency

This looks to be answered many different times but I can't seem to get it working with my implementation. I am trying to format and limit the data in a sap.m.Input element. I currently have the following:

```
var ef_Amount = new sap.m.Input({
  label: 'Amount',
  textAlign: sap.ui.core.TextAlign.Right,
  value: {
    path: '/amount',
    type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency'
  }
});
```

The first problem is that it kind of breaks the data binding. When I inspect the raw data (with Fiddler) submitted to the server it is an array like this:

```
"amount": [1234.25,null]
```

The server is expecting a single number and as such has issues with the array.

When I use the following, the binding works as desired but no formatting is performed.

```
var ef_Amount = new sap.m.Input({
  label: 'Amount',
  textAlign: sap.ui.core.TextAlign.Right,
  value: '{/amount}'
});
```

The second problem is that the data entered is not limited to numbers.

I have tried using sap.m.MaskedInput instead but I don't like the usage of the placeholders because I never know the size of the number to be entered.

And lastly, it would be nice if when focus is placed on the input field, that all formatting is removed and re-formatted again when focus lost.

Should I be looking into doing this with jQuery or even raw Javascript instead?

Thank you for looking.

Comment: with the tag sapui5 you reach more users. the tag sapui5 covers both sapui5 and openui5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the **array output** is a normal one according to documentation. So you need to teach your server to acccept this format or preprocess data before submission;
2. this **type is not intended** to limit your data input;
3. good feature, but ui5 does not support this, because the Type object **has no idea about control** and it's events like "focus" it only deals with data input-output. So you have to implement this functionality on your own via extending the control or something else.

I would suggest using **amount and currency separately**. It's likely that user should be allowed to enter only valid currency, so you can use a combobox with the suggestions of the available currencies.

Comment: Ok, based on this information it looks like extending the control is my best option in order to limit the data input to currency as well as finding a way to unformat / format the data on a focus gain / loss.

Comment: I can imagine the following solution:

1. you handle the "focusin" and "focuseout" events on "Input" control;
2. when user focuses in, you rebind the control to the same path but without using the data type (it will turn the value in a raw format)
3. when user focuses out, you bind the control to the same path but WITH usage of data type (the type fill format your data back)
4. you can prevent user from typing crap by using the "liveChange" event of the input (use a regular expression inside to replace the wrong chars)

Comment: The bound data item in the model does not appear to get updated prior to rebinding the 'value' property. I end up with the old data being displayed and formatted. There wouldn't happen to be something like an 'afterfocusout' event? In such a way that the data model is first updated.

Comment: It would be great if you do this in Plunker, because looking into coding is much easier and I could have a look and suggest something, You can take this template https://plnkr.co/edit/qBNu4T as a basis.

Comment: Ok, I hashed together some pretty quick code in Plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/WgIMPfaY1TN5ibX6A6t3). I am using a formatter in the focus out. This allows me to format the number and doesn't break the binding the server is looking for. So, the input field loads with a default value but if I enter a different number, say 1400.67 and change focus, the input field has the initial data value formatted and set.

Comment: Here is one problem: when user focuses out, the changed value does not get saved in the model (user has to press "enter" button manually), which is also not a good user experience.

Answer (score 0):

So, after much work and assistance from @Andrii, I managed to get it working. The primary issue was that **onfocusout** broke the updating of the model and the **change** event from firing. Simply replacing **onfocusout** with **onsapfocusleave** took care of the issues.

The final code in the **init** method of my custom control:

```
var me = this;
var numberFormat = sap.ui.core.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance({maxFractionDigits: 2});

me.addEventDelegate({
  onAfterRendering: function() {
    // for formatting the figures initially when loaded from the model
    me.bindValue({
      path: me.getBindingPath('value'),
      formatter: function(value) {
         return numberFormat.format(value);
      }
    });
  },
  onfocusin: function() {
    // to remove formatting when the user sets focus to the input field
    me.bindValue(me.getBindingPath('value'));
  },
  onsapfocusleave: function() {
    me.bindValue({
      path: me.getBindingPath('value'),
      formatter: function(value) {
        return numberFormat.format(value);
      }
    });
  }
});
```